# How call a method from a view in asp.net mvc 5.2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How call a method from a view in asp.net mvc 5.2 ?

view:

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="logout">Contact</a>
```

HomeController:

```
public ActionResult logout(){
    Session ["empleado"] = null;
    return View ("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");  
}
```

Comment: tell us what method do you want to call exactly?

Comment: see @helper in razor,is it you want?

Comment: You'll need to add some more explanation as to what you are trying to do and what problems you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure 'call a method' and 'generate a link' are the same thing

**which do you want to do?**

> How call a method from a view in asp.net mvc 5.2 ?

```
@Html.Action("logout", "Home")
```

will render the result of the action to the page - given the name of the action and that you are returning an Index view, I doubt this is actually what you want

> `<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="logout">Contact</a>`

```
@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "logout", "Home")
```

will render an `<a>` : `<a href='~/Home/logout'>Contact</a>` which seems to be what you are after

(used the same text as example, you probably don't want a link that says "contact" to logout the user...)

Comment: Check this out http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/274/introducing-taghelpers-in-asp-net-mvc-6

Comment: @psylogic Thanks for this - am I right that this is new for MVC6?  The question mentions MVC5.   But ultimately, it's really not clear what the question is asking, so had to guess at the most likely.